# Number of monotonic paths in a rectangular grid avoiding certain points

Tags: algorithm

In a rectangular grid of size m*n, the number of paths from (0,0) to (m,n) (without backtracking) is (m+n)!/(m!*n!). Now if there are certain points in the grid which we want to avoid, how can we calculate the number of paths avoiding those points?

Comment: what have you considered so far?

Comment: you forgot the factorial in the numerator, by the way

Comment: By the way, this is a simplified version of the question from the [running contest on Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/SEP12/problems/KNGHTMOV).

Comment: and why do you think that there are C(m,n) paths for a normal grid? Check the 2x3 case. I think there're 3 monotonic paths there, while your statement predicts `5! / (3! 2!)`, which is 10.

Comment: In the 1x2 case where there are 3 monotonic paths.

Comment: @Qnan In a grid that has 2x3 *lines*, the m and n are actually 1 and 2, because the numbers go from 0.

Comment: @RafałDowgird I see. We have a slightly different notion of grid size, then.

Answer (score 2):

The (recursive) equations defining the solution are as follows:

- number of monotonic paths from (m,n) to (m,n) is 1
- number of monotonic paths from any forbidden point to (m,n) is 0, same for points with first coordinate greater than m or second greater than n.
- number of monotonic paths from any other point (x,y) to (m,n) is the sum of:

  - number of paths from (x+1,y) to (m,n) and
  - number of paths from (x,y+1) to (m,n) (see above for dealing with the increment moving us out-of-grid)

Obviously, as Qnan stated, you need to use dynamic programming (i.e. memorize partial solutions to avoid exponential time) to solve these for (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a reasonable analytical solution for a grid with exactly `k` points blocked, but one can count the paths using a dynamic programming algorithm.

An analytical solution is troublesome because the number of blocked paths will depend no only on the number of blocked nodes and position of each node, but also on their relative positions. E.g. in a 4x4 grid, these two configurations give very different results:

```
....      ....
..x.      .xx.
.x..      ....
....      ....
```

It is easy to see that the former allows for only two monotonic paths, while the latter has at least 5.

Answer (score 0):

A natural question here is to ask: for any given k, what is the maximum number of monotonic paths avoiding a set S of k points (where the maximum is over all possible sets S)?

This is actually an open problem raised in a paper of Johnson, Leader and Russell: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4643.pdf